# Create text file in oracle using sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle, text-files

I need to grab data from some oracle database tables and format it into a fixed width text file.
I want to know if its possible to create a text file using sql.
I looked at some stuff and found the bc and xp_cmdshell but they are a bit confusing.

I am pretty new to sql and oracle databases.

Is this possible and how can I begin?

I don't need to open a file or check for existing file, overwriting is fine, what ever makes it easiest.
I don't need anything big or complex, a simple script to grab values and create a text file.

Just an update:
I don't think bcp works in the toad for oracle editor.
I found this tutorial here: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/exporting-data-programatically-with-bcp-and-xp_cmdshell
but the first bcp command does not compile, it says invalid sql query

Comment: Where do u need the file?

Comment: @SOaddict - I would like the file to be on my computer, preferably in my documents.

Comment: So you are basically trying to run a simple SQL query and you want to have those results in a text file.Am i correct?

Comment: You can write a shell script which has all oracle connection details

Comment: that will export the file into the server.

Comment: @SOaddict - I am not familiar with shell scripting and I would prefer to just have the file locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the SQL*Plus client, you can spool to an output file. Here is a sample SQL*Plus file:

```
set serveroutput on size 1000000
set linesize 150
spool C:\path_to_file\filename.extension

-- Your SQL statement
select columns
from table
where somecondtion;

-- Your next SQL Statement
select ...
from ...;

spool off
```

Comment: I am trying to use what you provided but I am getting an error: "Invalid SQL Statement". Not sure what I am missing, but the word off in the last line is underlined red. I am using Toad for Orcale, so not sure if this code works.

Comment: SQL*Plus is an Oracle command line client that will run the above script. I haven't used Toad in years but I suspect you may be able to execute this by running it as a _script_ not a _SQL_ _statement_ (probably a different button or command). I'm sure Toad has documentation on running _scripts_ and how to _spool_ an output file.

Comment: I did find an Execute as Script button and it worked. The file was created in the path specified. Any idea how to fix the columns not displaying correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use sqlplus command line tool todo this. See [oracle manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch6.htm) for formatting hints.

Comment: When providing an answer, show an actual example, even if a generic example is all that you can do to start